# Gatsby or NextJS for ecommence complex site

Tags: next.js, gatsby

I have below applications:

- a magento2 e-commence site with Restful API in docker
- some nodejs micro service Restful API in docker

i have question, if i wanna to develop a ecommence + user portal frontend site, which framework i should pick? NEXTJS or GATSBY?

given that:

- i have over 30000 user
- I need to serve more than 10 locales, and may keep increasing
- I need to serve more than 10 countries , and may keep increasing , and each of those may many different localisation setting
- i have over 10 store represent 10 countries , each of them has more than 20 products, and may increasing

Answer (score 3):

I do not agree with [Zain Ui Hassan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62830616/5585371).

With Gatsby, it doesn't matter the amount of asynchronous data your site will have, the number of pages, or the dynamic data. In the end, it is a React site with all the content already fetched and served, so it's blazing fast. Moreover, you have a bunch of official plugins that manage all your needs.

- You will be able to handle a [S3 AWS deploy](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-s3/).
- [Multilanguage support](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-i18n/) with redirections included and dynamic routes
- CMS fetched data with a bunch of multiple CMS support ([Contentful CMS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-contentful/?=contentful%20source), [DatoCMS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-datocms/?=datocms%20source), [Strapi](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-strapi/?=strapi), [Netlify CMS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms/?=netlify%20cms), markdown files, JSON files, custom database, etc).
- Lambda support.

You don't need a Node server to deploy or view a Gatsby website since it renders a static HTML, so you don't need any extra configurations, just a server, all pages are created in the build time. Next.js needs server-side customization and rendering.

In addition, it's SEO-friendly, you can easily customize your components to render (even when the page is already created) with the proper country-oriented data.

In the end, it's completely up to you, but in my opinion, you will need fewer configurations and you will have less trouble using Gatsby, due to the few and easy configurations.

In terms of community, both have great support so it's a tie.

Personally, I think that the only area where Next.js would be the better option at the moment is scalability since Gatsby, especially in large-scale projects, will increase the deploy time (up to 10 minutes, which is not ideal) but I know they are working on improving this by implementing incremental builds. I reduced my deploy time from 8 minutes to 2.

---

> but i do want to know more, if a page path that depends on user, e.g
> `/myinbox/letter-from-tom-to-stanley`, each user may have different msg
> on their inbox, and each inbox may have different path depend on user

This will depend on your code logic rather than the framework used. Of course, you are able to achieve this both with Gatsby and Next. I'm doing similar stuff with Gatsby and I have no issues. Of course, you will need a back end logic sometimes (database stuff), but it's completely doable.

---

Answering your question. It's a personal choice and you can fit your specifications with both (like the other question shows). I would choose Gatsby because it's more oriented towards SEO (conversion), easy to maintain if it's well structured (data-entity in CMS, etc), the plugin support, and the fewer (minimum) server configurations since you are uploading a `/public` compiled folder.

Useful articles:

- [https://dev.to/jameesy/gatsby-vs-next-js-what-why-and-when-4al5#:~:text=JS%20is%20mainly%20a%20tool%20for%20server%2Dside%20rendered%20pages.&text=Gatsby%20can%20function%20without%20any,HTML%20page%20from%20the%20server](https://dev.to/jameesy/gatsby-vs-next-js-what-why-and-when-4al5#:%7E:text=JS%20is%20mainly%20a%20tool%20for%20server%2Dside%20rendered%20pages.&text=Gatsby%20can%20function%20without%20any,HTML%20page%20from%20the%20server)
- https://www.gatsbyjs.org/features/jamstack/gatsby-vs-nextjs
- https://medium.com/frontend-digest/which-to-choose-in-2020-nextjs-vs-gatsby-1aa7ca279d8a

Comment: actually i like gatsby too, but, they have issue on routing if only deploy to s3, let say you will deploy ur app in one of the folder of a s3 bucket,  and your path will be /myfolder/{lang}/pages/{dynamic id}/{daynamic id}, gatsby seem have issue on this with client path routing, and given that i cant pre generate the lang path

Answer (score -1):

Gatsby is used for static websites where you don't have lots of dynamic data. If you are building complex level website go with NextJs.

Next.js has the best-in-class "Developer Experience" and many built-in features; a sample of them are:

An intuitive page-based routing system (with support for dynamic routes)
Pre-rendering, both static generation (SSG) and server-side rendering (SSR) are supported on a per-page basis
Automatic code splitting for faster page loads
Client-side routing with optimized prefetching
Built-in CSS and Sass support, and support for any CSS-in-JS library
Development environment which supports Hot Module Replacement
API routes to build API endpoints with Serverless Functions
Fully extendable

https://nextjs.org/

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i dont want a server, i MUST deploy in s3

Comment: Making server is not necessary in NextJs, you can build your application/website without creating server, just make pages and components and you are good to go. But this won't be deployed in S3 bucket like a React app, you will have to configure to run it as it needs Node server

Comment: i understand it need a node server,  but i do want to know more, if a page path that depends on user, e.g /myinbox/letter-from-tom-to-stanley, each user may have different msg on their inbox, and each inbox may have different path depend on user

Comment: BTW for my point of view, Serverless = everything without server, api use lambda, frontend use s3, auth use cognito/auth0

Comment: You can read about it from here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

Comment: yea, i read it before, it seem cant handle user depend path, it suggest to fetch the data at client side, therefore you cant use get static props, and get server props also not able as i said only s3